# Get Posts by tag from a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags, get-posts

I have a custom post type called `product`, which have two custom taxonomies named as `product_tags` & `product_categories`.

In My `Product Categories` archive page, I am listing tags. My requirement is, when any one will click on any tag, the products belongs to the tag will be listed. But condition is products will be only from the specific category or from the child category of that.

Example: In `Men` Product category archive section, `Headwear` is a tag. When user clicks on the "Headwear" products from the `Men` or Child Cat of `Men` should be listed there, not from 'Women'.

Comment: are you using woo-commerce?

Comment: @WisdmLabs No, I am using MarketPress.